# desktop apps running on browser: XAMPP+sqlite+PHP. is it a good idea?

Tags: php, web-applications, desktop

We are about to start to develop relatively small db desktop apps, running on a browser (analogous to a cashier system).

We think the app could be distributed with a standalone webserver (XAMPP) + PHP + sqlite. Source code can be encrypted via ionCube.

We already have web-apps and we wish to port them to be used locally, almost with the same code. That's the main idea.

We think it is a good solution. But [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870/why-dont-people-use-php-for-desktop-applications) it doesn't feel like it.

Is there some trouble we have not seen/missed? Are there problems that we should consider further?

update:
* the installation of XAMPP consists of unzipping a folder
* to update I can replace/patch the folder containing my code (automatically, the user doesn't have to do anything)
* unistall is deleting the folder
* backups are not a problem...

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of ionCube, you should consider compiling such an app with HipHop. This gives you an executable with built-in webserver IIRC, so might make such a setup less flaky.

Comment: Btw, have you ruled out HTML5 WebApps? Mandating a current webbrowser (with sqlite JavaScript support) seems less support-needing than a XAMPP setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you mention discusses something else: The use of PHP for real, native standalone desktop applications using a toolkit like GTK.

What you are planning to do strikes me as similarly problematic, though. What comes to mind straight away:

- A webserver installation is a relatively "big thing" where a lot can go wrong (e.g. ports already in use by other applications; firewalls and security suites blocking things). Manual installation would be mandatory
- You'll have updating troubles (what if you need to update the client installation to a new version of PHP or mySQL?)
- The application must be uninstalled manually
- Updating the application and making backups is difficult

it's not impossible - it just feels very, very kludgy compared to a standalone .exe installation.

Comment: * the installation of XAMPP consists of unzipping a folder
* to update I can replace/patch the folder containing my code (automatically, the user doesn't have to do anything)
* unistall is deleting the folder
* backups are not a problem... if these are the possible objections, then I think we're on a right track

Comment: @arod deleting the folder is going to give trouble if Apache and mySQL are registered as services. Anyway, if you can install and uninstall manually and in person, this won't be a problem. Automatically, there's too much that can go wrong IMO.